# Upgrade of ng-cli to version 1.6.3 generates error when creating new application

Tags: angular, angular5

I upgraded recently angular cli to 1.6.3. I also upgraded one of the projects on the same PC to Angular 5 from Angular 4.
While troubleshooting I did upgrade node to 9.3.0 and npm to latest. The error below is generated after I ran command `ng new my-app`
Anybody experienced that? any advice is appreciated.

As a result - I cannot create new Angular application:

> Error: Could not find an NgModule for the new component.

Comment: please add the output of ng -v

Comment: try to run `ng new my-app` from bash shell (git or cygwin)

Comment: Angular CLI: 1.6.3
Node: 9.3.0
OS: win32 x64
Angular:
...

Comment: @santosh - changing shell does not make any difference.

Comment: can you post the full error message (output ng generate), maybe there is hint in it

Comment: It is a full error message - I can generate components, services and etc in existing angular app - I cannot create new app only: full error is here: $ ng new my-app
Error: Could not find an NgModule for the new component. Use the skip-import option to skip importing components in NgModule.
Could not find an NgModule for the new component. Use the skip-import option to skip importing components in NgModule.